# Power BI DirectQuery : Pros & Cons of connecting Multiple Oracle Data source?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-datasource, powerbi-custom-visuals

I have been using Direct Query for accessing Oracle DB data, but the thought process is I have to access multiple Oracle DB source data to show the consolidated result in my report.

As for I have gone through in official sites [click on here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/desktop-directquery-about#performance-and-load-on-the-underlying-source), There are some cons for making a live connection to multiple Oracle DB approach.

Do you people have any suggestion/recommendation based on your live working experience?

Comment: You will almost universally see better performance when importing, rather than utilizing DirectQuery.

Comment: Correct Greggyb, But the thing is that customer don't want to store their financial data anywhere outside of their network... I don't have any option other than Direct Query, do you think of any better solution for this...

Comment: If they want to keep data resident within their network, I'd stand up SSAS for them, rather than DirectQuery-ing relational sources.